# Computing $E[ {\rm Tr}\{(ZZ^T)^2 \}]$ for $Z$ Gaussian.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Gaussian random vector with zero mean and $Cov(Z)=I$ where $I$ is identity matrix.

How to compute
\begin{align*}
E[ {\rm Tr}\{(ZZ^T)^2 \}]
\end{align*}

I know that $E[Z_i^4]=3$, so I think $E[ {\rm Tr}\{(ZZ^T)^2 \}]$ should be $3n$.

But, how to show this?
Thank you

Comment: $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ i.e. $Tr(ZZ'ZZ')=Tr(Z'ZZ'Z)=(\sum Z_i^2)^2$

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I see it know.

Comment: Dear @Saty.  So, is it $3n$ or $3n^2$??

Comment: $\chi^2_n$ has mean $n$ and variance $2n$

Comment: @Say Are you talking about Chi-Square distribution. For me $Z$ is Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_i$'s i.i.d  $\sim N(0,1)$ then $X=\sum Z_i^2 \sim \chi^2_n$. Now $E[Tr\{(ZZ')^2\}]=E[\{\sum Z_i^2\}^2]=E(X^2)$.

Now As $X\sim \chi^2_n$ we have $E(X^2)=Var(X)+E^2(X)=2n+n^2$
(i.e. the answer is neither $3n$ nor $3n^2$)

Comment: One more question why is $Tr(Z'ZZ'Z)=(\sum Z_i^2)^2$ and not $Tr(Z'ZZ'Z)=\sum Z_i^4$??

Comment: $Z'ZZ'Z=(Z'Z)(Z'Z)=(\sum Z^2_i)(\sum Z^2_i)$. To have a practical understanding just take $Z_{2 \times 1}=(z_1 \hspace{2pt} z_2)'$ and compute the above.